# Upvote/Downvote acts_as_votable gemfile Rails error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I installed a gem in my `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'acts_as_votable', '~> 0.10.0'
```

I keep getting this error:

```
/User/Name/seminar/project/config/routes.rb:11: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end put "like" to: "reviews#upvote" ^
```

I am unsure what I am doing wrong or what I currently have in my code, but I have followed a basic tutorial on youtube, but continue to get the errors.

This is my code in `controller.rb`:

```
def upvote
  @review= Review.find(params[:id])
  @review.upvote_by current_user
  redirect_to :back
end
```

This is my code in `routes.rb`:

```
resources :reviews do
  member do
    put "like" to: "reviews#upvote"
  end
end
```

This is my code for my `review.rb`:

```
class Review < ApplicationRecord
  acts_as_votable
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a `,` and (unrelated to this error, but will result in another one) a `/` in `routes.rb`; try this:

```
# routes.rb

resources :reviews do
  member do
    put "/like", to: "reviews#upvote"
  end
end
```

Comment: That seem to work, but now I have an error in my index: <td><%= link_to '+1', upvote_review_path(review), method: :put%></td> is the code I used.

Comment: What is the error? Since its a different error, i suggest creating another question with the relevant code.